# Control autoshape corner rounding for rounded rectangle in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2007

I have some textboxes in Word (some containing text, others dropped on to text with complex formatting)

I have set the autoshape to 'rounded rectangle'

The problem I have is that on the larger shapes, the corners are more like circle arcs, i.e. unlike in Visio, the roundness of the corner seems to grow proportionally to the size of the shape rather than staying put.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am guessing by the lack of response that this is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do it by dragging the yellow diamond handle that appears in the upper left once you have selected the shape.

Sourced from http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Word-Drawing-Graphics/34093550/how-do-i-change-a-corner-radius-for-the-rounded-corner-rectangle.aspx.

Comment: **Very important** in order to get the yellow diamond, you need to put your shape in a drawing zone

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe there is a precise way to do this, but sometimes I have a need to match the radius between different sized rounded rectangles. Let's say I have two rounded rectangles, A and B. If B is smaller or larger than A, then the radius is inherently different. To mitigate this, I make a copy of A and place it behind B. Then I use the yellow diamond to change the radius of B such that it perfectly matches A.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do think it is possible with the use of borders. simply use a border with a large enough width and the same colour as the rectangle and you will get rounded corners. Granted, you cannot use the border for anything else and you can also only apply this effect to all corners at once, but from what I found it's the best you can get.